# Customizing Survey Page and want to omit by Time within Timezone, possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So, I want to pop up a survey on my site *except* during a specific time range on my site.

For instance, if the time is between (local user/computer time).

9am -2pm -- 7 days/week
do NOT show the survey.

This has to be robust enough to cover other countries (timezones) other than the US.

I've been looking and haven't quite found what I need. Is this something doable or already avail in a plugin etc...?

A thought I had is getting the hour/minutes from the local users time from the converted epoch data and just suppress based on that range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you can do it in the following way:

1. Using `Date` object in Javascript, you read the actual time on client's browser.
2. Then, you check if its in range. In case afirmative, you show a dialog (i.e. using `JQueryUI Dialog`).

Something like:

```
function checkForSurvey(){
   var d = new Date();
   var hours = d.getUTCHours();   // Number between 0 and 23
   if ((hours < 9) || (hours > 14)){   // 14 = 2pm
      showSurvey();
   }
}

function showSurvey(){
   $('#survey').dialog();
}
```

Obviously, you can improve my code, but I think that you get the main idea of what I suggested.